# How do I fix error Unexpected identifier css

Tags: php, laravel, hyperlink

I am following a laravel beginners tutorial and need some help.
I am running the following line of code in my admin_master.blade.php

```
<link href="{{ asset(‘backend/assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-122.css’) }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However, I get the following message.

```
syntax error, unexpected identifier "css’", expecting ")"
```

I am running laravel 9.20.

Comment: this is most likely a typo. you probably need to use double quote. like this. 

<script src="{{ asset("assets/scripts/moment.min.js") }}"></script>

Comment: The issue is you are using "smart quotes", the `‘` and `’` characters are not the same as `'`

Comment: Thank you so much Jacob. That was my issue. My issue has now been fixed.